# How to create and redirect file descriptors other than stdin/stdout/stderr using Tcl?

Tags: tcl

Reading about bash exec one can create and redirect pipes other than the standard ones, e.g. `exec 3>4`.

Reading about [Tcl exec](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm) there is no mentioning of non-standard pipes. Seems explicit.

The use case is a launcher starting many executables communicating over multiple pipes (possibly circular fashion). I was thinking something like:

```
lassign [chan pipe] a2b_read a2b_write
exec a 3 3>@$a2b_write
exec b 3 3<@$a2b_read
...
```

...where 'a' is an executable taking a file descriptor argument controlling where a should write stuff, and vice versa for executable 'b'. Using the standard pipes does not work when executable communicate over multiple pipes.

I know how to do this using a named pipe, but would much rather tie pipe lifetime to that of the process'.

Comment: I've got this feeling that that's not supported, and the workaround is running a shell script to do this wiring up.

Comment: @DonalFellows Started out that way. Could not find how to create a process bound pipe such as the one returned by `chan pipe`. If channel file name could be retrieved the issue would be solved (passing filenames instead of file descriptors, e.g. /proc/123/fd/$a2b_write), but that does not seem possible either. Or fragile at least.

Comment: In sh, you can open new file descriptors (`exec 3>&4`, this is the `dup()` system call).   I don't think that Tcl has the `dup()` functionality.   I do not see it anywhere in the `chan` or `file` manual pages.

Answer (score 2):

Tcl has no built-in binding for `dup()` at all, and only uses `dup2()` in a very limited way (only for the three standard channels). Without those, this functionality is not going to work. This is where you need [TclX](https://github.com/flightaware/tclx), where you can take full control of the channel handling and process launching and do whatever you want (via `fork`, `dup` and `execl`; note that that's *not* at all like `exec` and much more like the POSIX system call).

Or do the trickery in a subordinate shell script.

Comment: The facts of the first sentence were found by grepping the sources; there's literally no built-in trickery available to hack around this. TclX's `dup` can do it all though; it does both dup() and dup2(), with which it does depending on what arguments you pass.